# Using type lambdas together with higher-kinded types in Scala: how to get compiler to infer types correctly?

Tags: scala, higher-kinded-types

Suppose I have trait that represents something like a polymorphic function, e.g.:

```
trait Func[A[X, Y]] {
  def apply[X, Y](a: A[X, Y]): A[X, Y]
}
```

Now I want to use my trait as a non-polymorphic function by passing type lambda as argument:

```
type single[T] = { type t[X, Y] = T }
val aInstance: Func[single[String]#t] = 
  new Func[single[String]#t] {
    def apply[X, Y](a: String): String = ???
  }
```

Now I have method `test` which does some useful things with `func`, e.g.

```
def test[A[X, Y]](f: Func[A]): Unit = ???
```

And I want to invoke `test` with `aInstance` without specifying type parameters by hand:

```
test(aInstance)
```

Unfortunately, this code does not compile (but `test[single[String]#t](aInstance)` does) with error messages:

```
[error] /test.scala:16:3: no type parameters for method test: (f: Func[A])Unit exist so that it can be applied to arguments (Func[[X, Y]String])
[error]  --- because ---
[error] argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
[error]  found   : Func[[X, Y]String]
[error]  required: Func[?A]
[error]   test(aInstance)
[error]   ^
[error] /test.scala:16:8: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Func[[X, Y]String]
[error]  required: Func[A]
[error]   test(aInstance)
[error]        ^
[error] two errors found
```

My question is: how can I modify these declarations to allow compiler to infer all required types automatically?

---

To those wondering why I declared `Func` as having `[X, Y]` but never used them in actual code there is a more real-world and less abstract example:

```scala
object GenericTest {
  trait Item { def name: String }
  class ItemA extends Item { def name: String = "a" }
  class ItemB extends Item { def name: String = "b" }

  trait MapFn[-A[X <: Item], +B[X <: Item]] {
    def apply[X <: Item](data: A[X]): B[X]
  }

  case class ItemsCollection[C[A <: Item]](a: C[ItemA], b: C[ItemB]) {
    def map[D[A <: Item]](f: MapFn[C, D]): ItemsCollection[D] =
      ItemsCollection(f(a), f(b))
  }

  // sometimes we want to store sequences...
  val itemSeq = ItemsCollection[Seq](Seq(new ItemA), Seq(new ItemB))
  // or transform them:
  val itemSet = itemSeq.map(new MapFn[Seq, Set] {
    override def apply[X <: Item](data: Seq[X]): Set[X] = data.toSet
  })

  // but one day we wanted to store just objects without any item-specific types... e.g. names:
  type single[X] = { type t[A] = X }
  val itemNames = itemSeq.map(new MapFn[Seq, single[String]#t] {
    override def apply[X <: Item](data: Seq[X]): String = data.head.name
  })

/*
[error] test.scala:28:27: no type parameters for method map: (f: MapFn[Seq,D])ItemsCollection[D] exist so that it can be applied to arguments (MapFn[Seq,[A]String])
[error]  --- because ---
[error] argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
[error]  found   : MapFn[Seq,[A]String]
[error]  required: MapFn[Seq,?D]
[error]   val itemNames = itemSeq.map(new MapFn[Seq, single[String]#t] {
[error]                           ^
[error] test.scala:28:31: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : MapFn[Seq,[A]String]
[error]  required: MapFn[Seq,D]
[error]   val itemNames = itemSeq.map(new MapFn[Seq, single[String]#t] {
[error]                               ^
[error] two errors found
 */
}
```

Comment: What's the use case here? Doesn't `trait Func[A[X, Y]] { def apply[X, Y](a: A[X, Y]): A[X, Y] }` reduce to `trait Func[A] { def apply(a: A): A }` with no loss of generality?

Comment: Not an answer but if you can do better than `type S[x, y] = single[String]#t[x, y]` and `aInstance: S` I'd be surprised.

Comment: @user31601, no, there are instances of `Func` which use these two arguments. This is just simplified example with all non-relevant parts removed.

E.g. `class B[X, Y]` and `Func[B]` works really well.

Comment: When you say they *use* those 2 argumenst... how? A class implementing the trait may make use of arguements, but the trait, as you've defined it does not. So why can't you just specify those generic arguments on the implementing classes?

Comment: That is a polymorphic function. Actually this code is a part of heterogenous collection. In real code instance of `Func` receives additional argument (implicit type class) which allows it to operate on these unknown `X` and `Y`. I just dropped parts which actually use these `X, Y` since they are just working fine and does not cause any inference issues.

Comment: @user31601, I added an example to clarify why I need these generics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referring to your `GenericTest`, there is no way to get Scala to infer that shape, because of [this closed-but-unfixed bug](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/5075#issuecomment-370148938).

One thing you can do is try to adapt [the technique of Unapply](https://typelevel.org/blog/2013/09/11/using-scalaz-Unapply.html), using implicit resolution to determine the likely candidate for `D`. This will probably entail defining your own typeclass and instances, not using the ones Scalaz supplies, and possibly changing how `MapFn` is declared to be more suitable for this pattern. Make sure that the instance that gives you `single` has the lowest priority, as it can always be used (every `T` is an `F[T]` if `F = Id`).

If you control the definition of `MapFn`, you may also move the `B` type parameter to a type member. Then the signature of `map` becomes

```
def map(f: MapFn[C]): ItemsCollection[f.B] =
```

You can add a subclass to `MapFn` that moves the type member back to a parameter for ease of `MapFn` creation.